# data mismatch with spark regexp_extract

Tags: regex, apache-spark

Sample Data:

```
https://www.test.com/document/101?ref=stringA&qid=e9f7a92b
https://www.test.com/document/102?ref=stringB
```

Regex: `ref=([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.?)/?`

Match1 is `stringA` and `stringB`

Doing the same in pyspark

```
spark.sql("select regexp_extract(url, 'ref=([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.?)/?', 1) c1 from my_table").show()
```

Output:

```
+---------------+
|c1             |
+---------------+
|stringA&       |
|stringB&       |
+---------------+
```

Comment: It seems you need to double the backslash, `'ref=([a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.?)/?'`

Comment: are you sure you don't need to "\\" before `.` ?

Comment: it worked with "\\\" before `.`